# Difference between using namespace std and using std::cin

Tags: c++

Can someone explain what we get when declare:

```
using namespace std;
```

and

```
using std::cin;
```

What are the differences?

Comment: One is a declaration, one is a directive.

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std;` imports every symbol in the `std` namespace into the present namespace. It is a *using-directive*. From the [c++ wiki page on namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

> ```
> using namespace ns_name;
> ```
>
> From the point of view of unqualified name lookup of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, every name from namespace-name is visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and namespace-name.

`using std::cin;` imports only the `std::cin` symbol into the present namespace. It is a *using-declaration.* From [the same wiki page as above](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

> ```
> using ns_name::name;
> ```
>
> makes the symbol name from the namespace ns_name accessible for unqualified lookup as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this using-declaration appears.